# NHibernate : recover session after connection lost

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate with SQL Server 2005 in a WPF client application.

If I manually stop the SQL Server service and then restart it the session doesn't automatically reconnect.

So far I'm doing this witch seems to work :

```
try
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // some select here
    }
}catch(Exception ex)
{                
    if(this.Session.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Session.Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate won't handle connection drops for you. For occasionally connected scenarios like this I'd look into using a local database as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134245/does-anyone-have-experience-creating-an-occasionally-connected-browser-app-with-n), and then use the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/sync/default(en-us).aspx) to synchronize the local and central databases. Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387034/microsoft-sync-framework-clashes-with-nhibernate-toomanyrowsaffectedexception).

Answer (score -1):

If the server just stops, I think there are other problems. I don't have any experience in WPF but there are a lot of questions related to nhibernate / WPF ([SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf+nhibernate)).

If the database connections drops sometimes you may take a look at the UnitOfWork pattern.

Comment: The connection doesn't drop, it's me manually stopping the SQL server service. I'd expect the session to automatically recover when starting the service again.