# ignore Castle ActiveRecord connection failure

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

I am using castle activerecord to persist my domain objects to a sql server database. If for whatever reason the database connection fails i need to be able to ignore it and carry on with the opperation of the program.

Comment: wouldn't it be more sensible to fix whatever is causing the connection failure?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** ignore connection errors. It's up to you to decide what to do in case of a connection failure. For example, if you query for some User entities and there's a connection error, what should NHibernate/ActiveRecord return? It can't possibly make up results.

If you're working with an occasionally connected scenario, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912048/nhibernate-recover-session-after-connection-lost).